# Arrow menu and line-height

Tags: html, css, height

I've got a problem with a menu, which would work great, but I've got longer menu item names, and they are messing up the layout. Can anybody help, I've run out of ideas.

### HTML

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Foobar</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Foobar</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-flat-style-breadcrumb-links-with-css">Foobar longer</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Foobar</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Foobar</a></li>
</ul>
```

### CSS

```
ul {
    margin: 20px 60px;
}

ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    width: 100px;
   margin: 15px 10px 0 0;
    text-indent: 35px;
    position: relative;
}

ul li:before {
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: -2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 30px 0 30px 30px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #fff;
    z-index: 0;
}

ul li:first-child:before {
    border-color: transparent;
}

ul li a:after {
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: -30px;
    border-style: solid;
 border-width: 30px 0 30px 30px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #ccc;
    z-index: 10;
}

ul li.active a {
    background: #2E6AB3;
    z-index: 100;
}

ul li.active a:after {
    border-left-color: #2E6AB3;
}

ul li a {
    display: block;
    background: #ccc;
}

ul li a:hover {
    background: pink;
}

ul li a:hover:after {
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent pink; 
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mani_mess/ksNr3/1791/).

The problem is that line-height is not only to the text, but to coloured background as well. I want to make the line-height smaller, that it will fit base height, and background with base height.

Thanks,
Mani

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/bb2t397u/

Answer (score 0):

Use `min-width` in `li` and `height` in `ul`: https://jsfiddle.net/ilpo/ksNr3/1793/

Comment: Ok it helped a lot, Thanks! but what should I do if I have other menu item long containing 4 words and I need to brake it in two lines, because I need menu in one row